# Simple question with magnetic fields

Tags: magnetic-fields

On my test of today was the following question:  "an aluminium block moves with a constant speed over a road, ahead  of it is a magnetic field. Does the speed change when it enters the magnetic field?" The block was moving from left to right on the paper and the magnetic field lines were going inside the paper. The magnetic field was to the right of the car. I have no idea what the answer to this was, any help?

Comment: Google ["eddy currents"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eddy%20currents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your block enters the magnetic field, currents will be induced (eddy currents due to a change in the magnetic flux across the metal plate - which will induce currents that try to resist that change).

Currents flowing in a conductor generate heat - energy is lost by the system.

The only place where that energy can come from is the kinetic energy of the block.

This is assuming (not stated) that there are no other forces acting on the block - in other words, no propulsion and no friction. Because otherwise the speed of the block would be anyone's guess...!

Comment: So what you're saying is it would slow down?

Comment: @wowlolbrommer yes it would slow down.